# Se detiene la aplicación y al instalarla

Tags: java, android

Soy nuevo por acá, y también nuevo en el mundo de la programación Android.
Les comento, estoy realizando un juego de un romopecabezas y estoy haciendo el menú, con 4 `ImageButtons` y 1 `ImageView`, pero el problema es cuando intento instalar la aplicación en mi dispositivo android o en el emulador, aparece el mensaje "se ha detenido la aplicación". Pongo lo que me aparece en el LogCat y el código XML, ya que en el `main activity` no he tocado nada, esta por defecto de la `Empty Activity`.
PD: YA HABIA REALIZADO LA PREGUNTA PERO LA ELIMINE SIN QUERER
De antemano, muchas Gracias

> LOGCAT 09-10 02:46:03.126 27138-27138/? I/art: Late-enabling
>   -Xcheck:jni 09-10 02:46:03.257 27138-27143/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe 09-10 02:46:03.257 27138-27143/? I/art:
>   Debugger is no longer active
>       Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
>       Enter while loop. 09-10 02:46:03.550 27138-27138/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/jorge.puzzlemania-1/lib/arm64 09-10 02:46:03.570
>   27138-27138/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main
>   process 09-10 02:46:03.741 27138-27147/? I/art: Enter while loop.
>   09-10 02:46:03.773 27138-27138/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method
>   android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 09-10 02:46:03.990 27138-27147/?
>   I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10 02:46:04.325
>   27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:04.339 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop.
>   09-10 02:46:04.935 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while
>   loop. 09-10 02:46:04.951 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter
>   while loop. 09-10 02:46:05.416 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art:
>   Enter while loop. 09-10 02:46:05.690 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania
>   I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10 02:46:06.115
>   27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.119 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.120 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS
>   objects, 2% free, 174MB/178MB, paused 476us total 5.414ms 09-10
>   02:46:06.121 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Starting a blocking
>   GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.133 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter
>   while loop. 09-10 02:46:06.134 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art:
>   Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(384B) AllocSpace
>   objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 174MB/178MB, paused 522us total
>   13.480ms
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.159 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.161 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc concurrent
>   mark sweep GC freed 5(152B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2%
>   free, 174MB/178MB, paused 516us total 26.595ms
>       Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 466MB allocation
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.186 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.188 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc concurrent
>   mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2%
>   free, 174MB/178MB, paused 513us total 26.314ms 09-10 02:46:06.188
>   27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed
>   to allocate a 489411624 byte allocation with 4185704 free bytes and
>   17MB until OOM" 09-10 02:46:06.188 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania
>   I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.193 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.194 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc sticky
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4(1456B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS
>   objects, 2% free, 174MB/178MB, paused 449us total 5.358ms
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.206 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.207 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc partial
>   concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(144B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS
>   objects, 2% free, 174MB/178MB, paused 490us total 13.458ms
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.232 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.234 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc concurrent
>   mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2%
>   free, 174MB/178MB, paused 491us total 26.463ms
>       Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 466MB allocation
>       Starting a blocking GC Alloc 09-10 02:46:06.259 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop. 09-10
>   02:46:06.260 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Alloc concurrent
>   mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2%
>   free, 174MB/178MB, paused 482us total 26.244ms 09-10 02:46:06.261
>   27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed
>   to allocate a 489411624 byte allocation with 4185704 free bytes and
>   17MB until OOM" 09-10 02:46:06.261 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania
>   D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap 09-10 02:46:06.280
>   27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM 09-10
>   02:46:06.281 27138-27138/jorge.puzzlemania E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: jorge.puzzlemania, PID: 27138
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 489411624 byte allocation with 4185704 free bytes and 17MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:655)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1157)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:879)
>           at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:530)
>           at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:351)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
>           at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>           at jorge.puzzlemania.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2687)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2799)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1537)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6269)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 09-10
>   02:46:08.745 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while loop.
>   09-10 02:46:12.097 27138-27147/jorge.puzzlemania I/art: Enter while
>   loop.

CóDIGO XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/IMB_ajustes"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/boton_de_ajustes"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ajustess" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/IMB_libre"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/boton_de_estilo_libre"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/estilolibre"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="300dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="192dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/IMB_simple"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/boton_de_partida_simple"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/partidasimple" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/IMb_reglas"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/boton_reglas"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/reglas" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IMG_menu"
    android:layout_width="448dp"
    android:layout_height="208dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/IMb_reglas"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imagen_menu"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/menuu" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Quisieran saber porque se detiene mi aplicación. Si alguien me puede ayudar. No sé si será por el peso de las imágenes, la que más pesa es la de fondo, con 38MB. Es solo esto, que no se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: Según se ve en el `Log` es una excepción `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Revisa que no estés cargando en memoria imágenes muy grandes o que no tengas ningún bucle en el código que no termine nunca. Un saludo

Comment: Hola tocayo, te comento nuevamente que 38MB para una imagen en una aplicación móvil es demasiado, considera optimizar las imágenes ya que se esta terminando la memoria al tratar de manipular las mismas en memoria,  saludos!

Answer (score -1):

lo mas probable es que te hayas quedado sin memoria ram por cargar imagenes muy pesadas, pero podrias

- Reducir el tamano de las imagenes
- Poner en tu manifest.xml el siguiente 2 lineas dentro de application

  ```
  <application
       <!--Los demas atributos-->
       android:largeHeap="true"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       <!--Los demas atributos--> 
  >
  ```

Comment: Gracias a Todos. Fueron de mucha ayuda. Perdón por contestar tarde, mucha tarea.